# ImagePullBackOff issue bitnami rabbitmq-exporter, k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We are facing an issue that fails to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter from Dockrhub.

```
kubectl get statefulset rabbitmq -o yaml

 name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBIT_URL
          value: http://localhost:15672
        - name: RABBIT_USER
          value: user
        - name: PUBLISH_PORT
          value: "9419"
        - name: RABBIT_CAPABILITIES
          value: bert,no_sort
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 6
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: metrics


 name: RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
              name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-password
              name: rabbitmq
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
           
but we have issue with the RabbitMQ matrics.

# kubectl get pods --selector app=rabbitmq

NAME         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-0   1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          5d15h
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
pod status 

rabbitmq-0                                             1/2     ImagePullBackOff             0                 5d15h
redis-master-0                                         2/2     Running                      0                 5d15h
It's not available in Docker Hub.

docker pull bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
```

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

So , we are faild to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter specific version as it is not available in the docker Hub.

Would anyone be able to offer suggestions to address this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.